# Modifying a file based off the last match found

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

I'm trying to first read from the file and then write to the file based off the user input. If it finds the user input it needs to continue looking until it finds the last entry and then adds it on the line below. Right now it can find all the entries and add it below it, but its unable to find just the last entry. How would I go about skipping the entries it finds until it gets to the last entry?

```
import fileinput


ldev_number = input("Enter ldev_number:")
for line in fileinput.input(r'path', inplace=1):

    line_data = line.strip() #removes line
    print(line_data), #preserve old content

    if ldev_number in line:

        print(ldev_number) #add new data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best way to do it but I was able to accept user input and then once it found a match(triggered_match) it started the cycle to see how many entries there were that matched the text. Once it found the last one the previous match was set to True, the triggered_match was set to false so you knew you were at the bottom of the matches. The extra variable "first_match_only" makes sure it only prints it the first time it finds a match throughout the file(in case there is more matches at the bottom of the file). If it was unable to find the match in the file it just adds the entry to the bottom of the file.

```
import fileinput
import re

class Horcm():
    driver = None
    def __init__(self):

    group_name = "test_123"
    device_name = "test_1234"
    array_serial = "8998"
    array_ldev = "3794"
    mirror_unit = "0"
    IP_address = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
    horcm102 = "horcm102"
    found_in_file= self.horcm_match(group_name, device_name, array_serial, array_ldev, mirror_unit)

    self.add_horcm_inst(found_in_file, group_name,device_name, array_serial, array_ldev, mirror_unit, IP_address, horcm102)

    def horcm_match(self,group_name, device_name, array_serial, array_ldev, mirror_unit):
    # initalize variables
    previous_match = False
    first_time_matching_only = False
    found_in_file = False      # used in add_horcm function
    # search through file for matches
    for line in fileinput.input(
            r'path',
            inplace=1):
        triggered_match = False  # reset trigger
        line_data = line.strip()  # removes the extra line that is automatically added
        if group_name in line:  # If the user input is found in the file
            found_in_file = True   # determine if it needs to be added to file or not
            triggered_match = True  # set trigger
            previous_match = triggered_match  # store trigger
        if previous_match == True:  # If the previous line had a match

            if triggered_match == False:  # If the next line doesn't have a match

                if first_time_matching_only == False:  # if this is the first time finding a match

                    previous_match = False
                    first_time_matching_only = True  # Don't allow it to print other matches
                    print(group_name+"        "+device_name+"        "+array_serial+"        "
                          +array_ldev+"        "+mirror_unit)  # print the match below the last match
        print(line_data),  # preserve old content
    return found_in_file
    def add_horcm_inst(self,found_in_file,group_name,device_name, array_serial, array_ldev, mirror_unit, IP_address, horcm102):
        if not found_in_file :  # If you find it in the file there is no reason to add it to the file
            input_filename = 'path'
            with open(input_filename, 'a') as file1:    #open the file

                file1.write(group_name+"        "+IP_address+"      "+horcm102)    #add horcm_instance to bottom of file in right syntax

            with fileinput.FileInput(input_filename, inplace=True) as file: #open file again to add to the bottom of the "HORCM_LDEV" list
                for line in file:   # read line by line
                file_syntax = '#/************************* For HORCM_INST ************************************/' #find the bottom of the list
                    print(line.replace(file_syntax, group_name+"        "+device_name+"        "
                    +array_serial+"        "+array_ldev+"        "+mirror_unit+'\n'+'\n'+file_syntax), end='')  # add to list followed by file_syntax again

def main():

    Horcm()

if __name__ == '__main_' \
           '_':
    Horcm()
```